# the camel and the eye of the needle

Tags: lateral-thinking

A farmer told me, without lying:

"*you see this camel over there*" showing me a camel eating, "*it passed whole through the eye of a normal needle*"

How is it possible, knowing that I too do not lie and there are no word games?

Comment: `lateral-thinking` is probably the correct tag here.

Comment: why is it not close ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He did so

> as the camel was still a microscopic embryo.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the camel passed through

> [Needle's Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needle%27s_Eye) in South Yorkshire.

In fact, according to the Wikipedia article,

> "It was constructed approximately in the mid-late 18th century and believed to have been made in order to win a wager, where the second Marquis of Rockingham claimed he was able to 'drive a coach and horses through an eye of a needle'"

Comment: https://www.hidabroot.fr/article/136643/Chemot--Une-ouverture-comme-le-chas-dune-aiguille

Comment: +1, learned something today. But the OP states "a normal needle" though.

Answer (score 1):

It just

> walked past a needle. The statement says "by", not "through"

Comment: https://www.hidabroot.fr/article/136643/Chemot--Une-ouverture-comme-le-chas-dune-aiguille

Comment: there are no word games

Comment: @Dattier Words have meaning. If you tell me you might drive by my house tonight, I’d expect you to drive past it, not through the middle of it. The difference there is pretty huge, and is not just playing word games. If you intend to say “through the eye”, please say that.

Comment: yes, sorry my english is bad.